# Editting the registry in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, registry, edit, administrator

I used the code necessary to change the DWord of a registry in VB.NET however I need to always Right click and run as administrator for it to work. In order to prevent this I passed the administrator user credentials before executing the command, however I get an error message.

The code I used for this purpose is,

```
  Dim regVersion As RegistryKey
    regVersion = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\USBSTOR", True)

    Try
    Dim intVersion As Integer = 4     
        intVersion = regVersion.GetValue("Start", 0)
        intVersion = intVersion + 1            
    End If
        Dim p As New ProcessInfo(regVersion.SetValue("Start", intVersion))
        p.UseShellExecute = False
        p.Domain = "domain"
        p.UserName = "Yoosuf"
        p.Password = New System.Security.SecureString()
        Dim q As New System.Security.SecureString()
        For Each c As Char In 
            q.Password.AppendChar(c)
        Next
        Process.Start(p)
        regVersion.Close()
    Catch es As Exception
    End Try
```

However I receive an error message on the line

```
Dim p As New ProcessInfo()
```

Could anyone please let me know what is the mistake I have done

Comment: *"I passed the administrator user credentials before executing the command"* -- What does that mean?

Comment: As you can see in the try block I have given the windows administrator username and password

Comment: This code contains a lot of compile errors. Post the real code, then we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely because this code:

```
Dim p As New ProcessInfo(regVersion.SetValue("Start", intVersion))
```

doesn't make any sense. The [`ProcessInfo` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27xafxda.aspx) is expecting a string, which specifies the name of the file or application to be started. You've passed it the result of the [`RegistryKey.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kk9bxk9.aspx) method, which does not return a value.

Considering the real problem that you want to solve is,

> I need to always Right click and run as administrator for it to work

then the real solution is to add a manifest to your application that indicates it should be launched with administrative privileges. This would free you from having to right-click and explicitly choose "Run as administrator" each time. Instead, the application's process would be automatically elevated (if possible), or you would be prompted for permission by UAC.

To do this in Visual Studio for a VB.NET application, you need to modify the default manifest that is embedded into the application. Here are the steps:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and select "Properties".
2. Open the "Application" tab.
3. Click "View Windows Settings".
4. This opens the default manifest. Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to `requireAdministrator`.
   It should look like this:

   ```
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
   ```

Comment: Well the problem with the Manifest file is that it would make The Whole Program to run as administrator, which I do not want. Is it possible to create a Manifest to run ONLY this task under admin privileges

Comment: @Yoosuf: No. Elevation applies to processes only. The only way to run a particular "task" elevated is to run it as a separate process, and then adding a manifest to the executable for that process. Use `Process.Start` to launch the second executable, which will then prompt for elevation in the manner described above.